# Creating a node.js writable stream that proxies data to another writable stream, but prepends some of its own data first

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a writable stream that I would like to wrap with a stream of my own to prepend some data to whatever goes into the output stream.

I would normally write `inputStream.pipe(outputStream)`, where `inputStream` would provide `foo bar` and outputStream would recieve `foo bar`.

I would like to be able to write `inputStream.pipe(proxyStream('prefix ', outputStream))`, where `inputStream` would provide `foo bar`, but `outputStream` would recieve `prefix foo bar`.

I've tried the following code, but I get `Error: write after end` almost immediately after the pipe starts.

```js
class DetectStream extends stream.Writable {
  constructor (prefix, output) {
    super();
    this._output = output;
    this._output.write(prefix, 'utf-8');
  }
  _write (chunk, enc, next) {
    this._output.write(chunk, enc, next);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can modify the stream before passing to `.pipe()`

Comment: How can I modify the stream?

Comment: Read `inputStream`, modify, convert back to `WritableStream`, pass to `.pipe()`

Comment: In my use case, the `inputStream` is actually a constant "stream" of data, and it's impossible to consume it all.

Comment: _"it's impossible to consume it all."_ What do you mean? If the data cannot be modified, how can you append data to the stream? You can read the stream in chunks of bytes and pass the modified chunks to `.pipe()`

Comment: I would like to prepend data, not append data. If the API I'm designing should only provide an object that I can pipe data to, is there no solution?

Comment: Prepend and append are same in this instance; that is, modify the input stream.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125262/discussion-between-ari-lotter-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just write to the `outputStream` before piping the `inputStream` into it?

```
function proxyStream (prefix, output) {
  output.write(prefix, 'utf-8')
  return output
}
```

Then use it just like you said:

```
inputStream.pipe(proxyStream('prefix ', outputStream))
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't really solve the problem in cases where you'd like the prefix behavior to be encapsulated as part of a reusable Stream class (e.g. to avoid copy/pasting the same output.write(...)` code everywhere)